# How to turn off ANY optimisation flag in GCC

Tags: gcc

I am trying to understand how to turn off specific optimisation flags compiling with GCC. I understand that some flags have a `-fno` option, but most flags don't (from what I have seen). I am trying to compile a program with `-O1` flags but remove one of the flags in `-O1` for each compile.

For instance; `-fauto-inc-dec` does not have an equivalent `-fno-auto-inc-dec` flag that I could pass into the arguments like: `-O1 -fno-auto-inc-dec`.

Want to compile with `-O1` options but turn off specific options given by `-O1` to see the difference that causes.

Any help will be appreciated, unfortunately I'm new to this so I'm very much a beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in `man gcc`:

```
Most optimizations are only enabled if an -O level is set on
the command line.  Otherwise they are disabled, 
even if individual optimization flags are specified.
```

So basically by *not* passing any `-O` flags you aren't using configurable optimizations.

Also, `-O1` is not the default, `-O0` is.

You could also go from the opposite, disable all optimizations and enable "batches" by hand, i.e. have a look at `gcc -Q --help=optimizers`, see what optimizations are enabled at which level and strip those.

To address your concern that `-O*` options enable flags that aren't listed, I'd say that it's a man-page thing. Actively querying compiler on a particular architecture *should* give you an exhaustive list of optimization that will be enabled with a particular `-O` flag, so using `-O0` in combination with the list of those flags *should* produce exactly the same result.

Comment: I realise I have made a mistake by saying 'default', I've removed that now thanks. What I want to do is compile with ALL -O1 options but remove individual ones selectively to see the performance changes. Is this possible? I've read that you cannot get O1 performance by specifying all of the compiler flags because of the default variables it sets so listing all of the flags apart from the one I want to remove isn't an option.

Comment: Not from what I know. You could indeed go from the opposite, disable all optimizations and enable "batches" by hand, i.e. have a look at `gcc -Q --help=optimizers`, see what optimizations are enabled at which level and strip those.

Comment: Uhm, where did you get the info that you can't get `-O1` performance by specifying flags by hand?

Comment: The only piece I can find in the docs says that options listed in the man-page are not an exhaustive list, which makes total sense, since man-page is not architecture-dependent. But if you query the options that _are_ enabled by compiler on your particular architecture, you *will* get an exhaustive list.

Answer (score 2):

why not go the other way round? turn off *all* optimization with `-O0` and enable them selectively.

or if you prefer disabling them one by one, start with:

```
CFLAGS=-O0 \
      -fauto-inc-dec \
      -fcompare-elim -fcprop-registers \
      -fdce -fdefer-pop -fdelayed-branch -fdse \
      -fguess-branch-probability \
      -fif-conversion2 -fif-conversion \
      -fipa-pure-const -fipa-profile -fipa-reference \
      -fmerge-constants \
      -fsplit-wide-types \
      -ftree-bit-ccp -ftree-builtin-call-dce -ftree-ccp -ftree-ch \
      -ftree-copyrename -ftree-dce -ftree-dominator-opts -ftree-dse \
      -ftree-forwprop -ftree-fre -ftree-phiprop -ftree-slsr -ftree-sra \
      -ftree-pta -ftree-ter \
      -funit-at-a-time
```

(btw, all of this information is distilled from `man gcc`)